# users did not leave in the list of users in chat even they left

Tags: angular, laravel, chat

I made `chat` use `laravel` and `angular` I have the ability to return the users `join` in chat and the users `left`, my problem here is when `user` left, he remains in chat list of users join, even he left in chat, he is need to refresh for gives me that it is gone, and my angular site never get refreshed, so it always stays in chat list of users join

```
joinChat(id:any) {
    this.echo.join(`chat`)
      .here((users:any) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.users = this.users.filter(user => {
          return user.id !== id;
        }); 
        console.log('users here : ', this.users);
      })
      .joining((user:any) => {
        this.users.push(user);
        console.log('join : ', user.name, user);
      })
      .leaving((user:any) => {
        console.log('Leave : ', user.name, user);
        this.users = this.users.filter(userList => {
           user.id !== userList.id;
        }); 
      })
      .error((error:any) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The curly brackets in an arrow function forms a body of the function and you lose the implicit return. So you will need to explicitly return a value, otherwise the function will return `undefined`, thus the filter does not receive a predicate but a `void` and it cannot decide what to filter out.

Please try to add `return` inside the filter predicate function inside `.leaving(...)`

```
this.users = this.users.filter(userList => {
    return user.id !== userList.id;
});
```

or replace the curly brackets with parentheses.

```
this.users = this.users.filter(userList => ( // <-- parens here
    user.id !== userList.id;
));
```